# Uncaught ReferenceError: define is not defined in extension custom js

Tags: magento-2.1, javascript

i created the custom js for backend extension module like this:

custom.js:

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'mage/url',
    'jquery/ui'
    ], function ($, _,urlBuilder) {
    'use strict';
    $(function() { 
       console.log('test'); 
    });
});
```

default.xml :

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <link src="Namespace_Module::custom.js"/>
    </head>
    <body/>
</page>
```

but i got the following error like this :

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: define is not defined
    at custom.js:1
```

the problem might caused by require.js is loaded just before my custom.js

Answer (score 1):

As your script requires other scripts, yours should not be loaded with a layout update. It has to be loaded through requirejs to resolve dependencies:

file: `app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js`

```
var config = {
   map: {
       "*": {
           "myAwesomeCustomScript" : "Vendor_Module/js/custom"
       }
   }
};
```

Your custom.js file should be located at `app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/js/custom.js`

You will need to clear `pub/static/_requirejs` for your configuration to take effect.

The above tells Magento how your script file can be loaded. Now you need something else to require your script.

If your script is a controller script for an HTML element, you can use the following example in a phtml file:

```
<div data-mage-init='{"myAwesomeCustomScript":{}}'>
</div>
```

If your script is not bound to an HTML element, use the following example to load your script from a phtml file:

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "*": {
            "myAwesomeCustomScript": {
                "<option_key>": "<option_value>"
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Create a layout update file:
`app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/layout/default.xml`

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="my.awesome.script" template="Vendor_Module::script.phtml" />
    </body>
</page>
```

Create the phtml file: `app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/templates/script.phtml` and paste the script tag in it.

Comment: i want to use the js globally, and i'm not using any controller for this case

Comment: The second example could also be added to the head scripts section of your theme configuration, which removes the need to use a phtml file. You will have to use requirejs configuration if you need access to jquery, jquery-ui, etc

Comment: how to add it from extension?

Comment: I updated my answer with instructions on how to render the script tag from the extension.

Comment: can it work in adminhtml, because i use it this js in backend section, what is `"<option_key>": "<option_value>"` ?

Comment: sure, just replace /frontend/ with /adminhtml/  in the file paths

Comment: the object with <option_key>  and <option_value> can be used to pass options to your script.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change `define` to `require` like this

```
require([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'mage/url',
    'jquery/ui'
    ], function ($, _,urlBuilder) {
    'use strict';
    $(function() { 
       console.log('test'); 
    });
});
```